# Lostfocus issue when clicking on close button

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus

I am new here. And I am new to MS Access also. My problem is when I click on close button  of MS Access the following things happens:

1. I am using vba code to show a message in LostFocus event of User ID textbox. Here is the code

   ```
   Private Sub txtuserid_LostFocus()

   If Len(txtuserid.Value & nullvalue) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "You can not leave it blank."
   txtpswd.SetFocus
   txtuserid.SetFocus
   Else
   txtuserid = txtuserid.Value
   End If

   End Sub
   ```

   The messages shows up for 4 times.
2. After that the run-time error comes up saying this:

> Run-time error '2110':
>
> Library Systems can't move the focus to the control txtuserid.

with "End", "Debug", and "Help" buttons.

So my Question is, is there any way of stopping the VBA code on quitting the application or any better method to SetFocus to the desired field.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to the Unload event like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    If Nz(Me.txtuserid, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "You can not leave User ID blank."
        Me.txtuserid.SetFocus

        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Before the form closes, it will check to make sure there is a value in txtuserid.  If there isn't, it will throw a message box saying so, set the focus back on it, and cancel the Unload event, leaving the form open.

Answer (score 0):

In yourButton_Click Event to make sure something is there when trying to log in:

```
If Len(txtuserid & "") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing user id"
    txtuserid.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(txtPassword & "") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing password"
    txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I think I can't express my question very well. Because you are not getting the point. I mean if a user don't know the ID and Pass and he wanna close the app and if he clicks the close button (the close button means the button on top right corner of the window in red associated with Alt+F4 command and that button closes the whole application) the message pops up for four times and after that the debug error comes. GET IT???

Comment: change txtuserid_LostFocus()
to txtuserid_AfterUpdate() event

The LostFocus is going to fire every time the control has focus and then loses it, no matter what other control you click on. AfterUpdate is only going to fire after the value changes. Clicking on other controls, including the Close button, will not alter that value, and therefore will not fire an event.